# Speeding up the browsing of PDFs in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: windows, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have the most recent version of Adobe Acrobat 9 (9.0.5) installed on a relatively powerful workstation: A Windows 7 64 bit machine with **96 GB** of RAM and **two six-core** processors **Intel Xeon X5690 @ 3.47 GHz** (it's a workstation for scientific research)

What puzzles me is that the navigation of PDF documents is still not smooth on Adobe Acrobat 9 on my machine. For example, for a PDF that is **10 MB** in size, **eight pages long**, the scrolling is still not as smooth as I would expect it to be. It can take somewhere between **0.2 to 1 seconds** to move between pages or render a figure. Surely a fraction of a second is not *that much* that I can't read the PDF, but I often  scroll back and forth between pages, and when I do this the latency becomes more noticeable.

If I open the same file in [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) or in [PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) I can browse the PDF efficiently and move through pages with virtually no latency.

- Are there any options in Adobe Acrobat 9 that would **speed up** the scrolling/rendering of PDF files?
- **Why** is Adobe Acrobat so slow considering the specs of the machine? Why is it much slower than a relatively feature-rich PDF viewer/editor such as PDF-XChange Viewer? (note that, in contrast to SumatraPDF, PDF-XChange Viewer has significant editing capabilities).

Answer (score 1):

It is an uniprocessor 32bit program. Don't expect much from it. 
9.5 is minimum supported by adobe. Try that before Reader X